# Session ID lenght (characters) increases in weblogic 12c

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic12c, httpsession

We are migrating java application from java 1.6 to  1.8 and weblogic 10 to weblogic 12c,While we are checking the sessionID in Java 1.6 and weblogic10 ,which creating in jsp by using (`session.getId()`) ,we are getting session ID as  `Seesion =MT6GdnxL!1248180010!1971739048476`

but for java 1.8 and WebLogic 12c while checking Session ID length increases `Session =2jLynJb9dJOx8AvTjyWSK9UZblqFh4XU!-1492917096!1571733411581`

Can anyone please explain why this session ID length increases.
Due to the increase of length which is affecting our business logic

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your old weblogic (10) had a different session descriptor on the weblogic.xml.

If you want to keep the same sessionID lenght you should update your weblogic 12c's weblogic.xml:
`session-descriptor` node `id-length` value (default is 52).

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP587

Comment: thank u for your reply,we change the session descriptor to 52,still same issue we are facing

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.2/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>10.3.5</wls:weblogic-version>
 <session-descriptor>
   <id-length>52</id-length> 
 </session-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>

Comment: Ioannis is advising you to change `id-length` to something smaller than 52.